# How to make legacy HttpServlet Spring web aware

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

We have a legacy `HttpServlet` class that is the backbone of our application. At this point, the app doesn't have any Spring libraries in it. We are looking to introduce Spring, in particular so we can use Spring-Data in conjunction with Hibernate.

I was wondering if there is a way to make this legacy Servlet web-aware so we can have Request and Session scopes injected. In particular, we would like to be able to inject the `HttpServletRequest` object into some beans.

One of the main reasons we need to do this, is for a weird multi-tenancy solution we have in place. Hibernate can handle Multi-Tenancy using a combination of a `AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider` and a `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` When using Spring-JPA's Repositories, you lose control of the session creation. One way to take care of this is to implement the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` Since our tenant identifier is partially determined by something that comes in on the request, it is necessary to inject the request into our `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` implementation.

Also, it would be great to get Spring involved for all the other benefits it can provide in a legacy app.

Do you know how we can accomplish this?

Comment: No it isn't... Use a filter, to determine the current tenant, set it in a thread local and let the custom `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` implementation use the `ThreadLocal`. That way you can use it in very different and generic situations. That is the same I did for a client year ago (see [this post](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) and the code is free of use on [github](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils)) which already has a filter, hibernate integration , spring integration etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` within your web.xml, which will load your spring application context.

Then, within your servlet code, you access the context using `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext)` helper method.

Take a look at the Spring docs here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#web-integration-common